# Fixed effect model with time interactions

Tags: interaction, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

This seems like a somewhat basic question, but I'm struggling to figure this out and am hoping somebody can help:

I'm fitting a model with panel data and person-level fixed effects with the goal of looking at change in my outcome variable over time. I'm trying to decide if I should include time interactions with demographic variables or if this is unnecessary/harmful, as the inclusion of person-level fixed effects should mean that my demographic variables are already limited to change over time.

When I try this, I do get significant time interactions, but I'm not sure how to interpret the main effects in light of them. Is the change over time in a fixed effects model reflected in the main effects or the time interactions? If the latter, what do the main effects signify, as the person-level fixed effects should have removed everything except the time-varying components from the model?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming a person has fixed demographic features, so for example, male/female, which would be fixed for a person.

Then let's say you already have fixed effects per person, and you add an additional coefficient for male/female effects. This adds too many degrees of freedom.

For example, if all males score +1 over time. Then you could fit that with a coefficient of +1 on all male persons, or with a +1 on the male coefficient. Intuitively, +1 on the male coefficient is better, but that is then not part of the model. If you apply some regularization, such as a random effects model or ridge regression, you can solve that problem.

But with adding fixed effects per person and then also for demographic variables, your model has redundant coefficients and any significance results shouldn't be trusted (if at all btw, I'm a Bayesian :)).

Some packages will automatically add some regularization, or are built so that they will still assign the +1 to male somehow, but that changes the question. Assuming only fixed effects, your model becomes underspecified.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very good point. How would I go about specifying a model that would show me how demographic characteristics of persons impact change over the course of my panel in my primary outcome of interest (which is willingness to receive a given medical intervention)? You are correct that my demographic characteristics don't change over time, although willingness to receive the intervention does. Should I specify wave fixed effects rather than person fixed effects?

Comment: I think a random effects model is the way to go! In R you can use `glmer` or `lme4` I think, they also often have very good "vignettes" that explain a lot, and if you want more reading, I recommend https://xcelab.net/rm/statistical-rethinking/.

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, I'd appreciate an upvote!